# How to get Sqlserver database new rows in real time

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm developing a server program that needs to listen the database and retrieve new added rows in that time.How can I get data that is added in real time when program working ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IF you are coding C#, you can check following link:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc